# How to append <div> content in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to append below code in `jQuery` to display dynamically.

```html
<div id="lol">
  <tr data-userid="<%=iterator3.next()%>" data-mid="<%=iterator3.next()%>" >
    <td width="119">Practise Match</td>
    <%--  <td  width="119"><%=iterator3.next()%><td>
    <td  width="119"><%=iterator3.next()%> <td> --%>
    <td  width="119"><%=iterator3.next()%>pts<td>
    <td  width="119"><%=iterator3.next()%>rank<td>
  </tr>
</div>

$("#lol").append("<tr data-userid="+<%=iterator3.next()%>+" data-mid="+<%=iterator3.next()%>+" >"+  "<td >"+"Practise Match"+"</td>"+"<td >"+<%=iterator3.next()%>+"pts"+"<td>"+"  <td  width="119">"+<%=iterator3.next()%>+"rank"+"<td>"+"</tr>");
```

Is this correct or not?

Comment: That depends, where is this HTML coming from, and what does the templating do?

Comment: you maybe able to append this content using $('div selector on which to append').append('content to append'), but the template within this div content may not run as expected

Comment: can u please show the syntax..

Comment: $("#lol").append("<tr data-userid="+<%=iterator3.next()%>+" data-mid="+<%=iterator3.next()%>+" >"+  "<td >"+"Practise Match"+"</td>"+"<td >"+<%=iterator3.next()%>+"pts"+"<td>"+"  <td  width="119">"+<%=iterator3.next()%>+"rank"+"<td>"+"</tr>");

Comment: is this correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code to

```js
<div id="lol">
  <tr data-userid="<%=iterator3.next()%>" data-mid="<%=iterator3.next()%>" >
    <td width="119">Practise Match</td>
    <%--  <td  width="119"><%=iterator3.next()%><td>
    <td  width="119"><%=iterator3.next()%> <td> --%>
    <td  width="119"><%=iterator3.next()%>pts<td>
    <td  width="119"><%=iterator3.next()%>rank<td>
  </tr>
</div>

$("#lol").append(`<tr data-userid="${<%=iterator3.next()%>}" data-mid="${<%=iterator3.next()%>}">
    <td>Practise Match</td>
    <td>${<%=iterator3.next()%>}pts</td>
    <td width="119">${<%=iterator3.next()%>}rank</td>
  </tr>`);
```

I changed the code to `ES6` standard, that will give a `HTML` structure look.

You are missing `td` closing tag.

Hope this will help you.